Cannot move windows with tablet pen (Windows OS)
Also can't select text, move scrollbars, drag and drop, or move canvas in CLIP Studio Paint. Yet Firefox scrolling and Krita scrolling works just fine. Still can't select text in Firefox with tablet, have to use shift key.
I recently installed CLIP Studio Paint, and discovered that I can't move canvas with space-drag. In Krita, this hotkey worked just fine, but in CSP it just moves a tiny bit and then stops, and most of the time it doesn't move at all. Same thing with moving windows in general, it's like it obeys the very first milliseconds of input and then nothing after that. Then I noticed that I can't select text in notepad++, and I probably should be able to.
Some people recommended disabling "Windows Ink Workspace", I did so by running Windows-R gpedit.msc, Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows Ink Workspace -> Disable, but I've seen no effect.
I've also looked through Settings -> Devices -> Pen & Windows Ink, but I'm not sure what settings here do what.
What kind of helped, is changing shortcut in CSP for hand to button2, but now I have to hover over the board to move on canvas, a bit awkward.
My drawing tablet is HUION 420, my OS is Windows 10.
By the way, I'm quite surprised that Krita seems to have better hotkey support than CSP. CSP still has better vectors, from what I've seen on youtube.
Creating the new tags 'drawing-tablet clip-studio-paint' requires at least 300 reputation. Try something from the existing tags list instead. What a lovely site you got here.
